# Avoid notice of variable's not being set within dev mode

Tags: conditional, variable, devmode

With dev mode on, I'm getting a warning there is no entry.title, which I know about already because that's what I'm testing for:

```
{% if entry.title | length == 0 %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.section('sectionname').slug(craft.request.segment(2)).first() %}
{% endif %}
```

Is there a way to test for a variable without dev mode triggering this notice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've had luck using "is defined" before using other logic operators.

This should do it:

```
{% if entry.title is defined and entry.title | length == 0 %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.section('sectionname').slug(craft.request.segment(2)).first() %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I think you want to set `entry` to the new value if `entry.title` is not defined or is 0 length. Which is not what this code does.

Comment: You're right. I ended up using something slightly different in practice.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to set entry to a new value if `entry.title` is undefined or 0 length, try this:

```
{% if !(entry is defined and entry.title is defined and entry.title|length) %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.section('sectionname').slug(craft.request.segment(2)).first() %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Craft 2.6 you can do this cleanly with the `??` null-coalescing operator:

```
{% if not (entry.title ?? false) %}
  ...
```